# D3D11 DrawIndexed() is drawing to the wrong render target

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d, render-to-texture, oculus

I'm attempting to render a scene to two textures (left and right) for use with the Oculus Rift. When I set the render target to a 2D texture render view and call DrawIndexed() it renders to the back buffer instead of the texture. I'm using Visual Studio, and I've run the Graphics Diagnostics on it. On the DrawIndexed() event, it shows the render target is the texture, but the pixel history doesn't show the event. If I don't clear the backbuffer, the scene shows up on the screen.

In the following code, the RenderLeft() function should render an image to a plane on a green background with the render target set as the left render texture. Then RenderRight() should take the texture rendered by RenderLeft(), and render it to the plane, then output that on the back buffer. (Note: This isn't the normal set up. This is just to help see if the texture is being rendered to or not)

In the final output, there should be nothing on the left side of the screen, and on the right should be the source image inside a green rectangle on a black background.

Instead, I get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWrUt.png

RenderLeft is rendering to the back buffer, even though the render target is a texture, so then the texture used by RenderRight is just the color used to clear it.

Here is the code I'm currently using. I think I've included everything that's relevant.

```
// this is the function used to render a single frame
void  Direct3D::RenderFrame()
{

CreateTransforms(); //this creates matFinalLeft and matFinalRight, which is  (world matrix)*(view matrix)*(projection matrix) with the proper offsets for a stereoscopic view.

setVertices(); //this sets the vertex and index buffers.

setMainShaders(); // this sets the shaders used to render the 3D scene

RenderLeft(pTextureLeftRenderView, matFinalLeft, viewportLeft, true); //this renders an image to a plane on a green background. It SHOULD render to a texture.

RenderRight(backbuffer, matFinalRight, viewportRight, false);//this renders the render target from RenderLeft to the plane and renders to the back buffer.

swapchain->Present(0, 0); //output back buffer to screen.
}
```

This section should render a rectangle textured with an image to the left side of the render texture.

```
//Render the scene to the left side of a texture
void Direct3D::RenderLeft(ID3D11RenderTargetView *RenderTarget, D3DXMATRIX matFinal, D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport, bool clearRenderTarget){

devcon->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &RenderTarget, zbuffer);

devcon->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);

// update shader resources
devcon->UpdateSubresource(pCBufferPrimaryShader, 0, 0, &matFinal, 0, 0);
devcon->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &pTextureLeftResourceView);

// clear the depth buffer and render target texture
devcon->ClearDepthStencilView(zbuffer, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH, 1.0f, 0);
if (clearRenderTarget){
    devcon->ClearRenderTargetView(RenderTarget, D3DXCOLOR(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
}

// render to texture on left side (oculus) or full texture
devcon->DrawIndexed(6, 0, 0);
}
```

This section should render a rectangle with the texture from RenderLeft() to the back buffer.

```
//Render the scene to the right side of the back buffer
void Direct3D::RenderRight(ID3D11RenderTargetView *RenderTarget, D3DXMATRIX matFinal, D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport, bool clearRenderTarget){

//render to texture
devcon->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &RenderTarget, zbuffer);

devcon->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);

// update shader resources
devcon->UpdateSubresource(pCBufferPrimaryShader, 0, 0, &matFinal, 0, 0);
devcon->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &pRenderTextureLeftResourceView);


// clear the depth buffer and render target texture
devcon->ClearDepthStencilView(zbuffer, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH, 1.0f, 0);
if (clearRenderTarget){
    devcon->ClearRenderTargetView(RenderTarget, D3DXCOLOR(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
}

// render to texture on left side (oculus) or full texture
devcon->DrawIndexed(6, 0, 0);
}
```

Finally, the code that creates the various views and viewports

```
void Direct3D::InitD3D(HWND hWnd)
{
// create a struct to hold information about the swap chain
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC scd;

// clear out the struct for use
ZeroMemory(&scd, sizeof(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC));

// fill the swap chain description struct
scd.BufferCount = 1;                                    // one back buffer
scd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;     // use 32-bit color
scd.BufferDesc.Width = screen_width;
scd.BufferDesc.Height = screen_height;
scd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;      // how swap chain is to be used
scd.OutputWindow = hWnd;                                // the window to be used
scd.SampleDesc.Count = 4;                               // how many multisamples
scd.Windowed = TRUE;                                    // windowed/full-screen mode
scd.Flags = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH;

// create a device, device context and swap chain using the information in the scd struct
D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL,
    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
    &scd,
    &swapchain,
    &dev,
    NULL,
    &devcon);

// create the depth buffer texture
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC texd;
ZeroMemory(&texd, sizeof(texd));

texd.Width = screen_width;
texd.Height = screen_height;
texd.ArraySize = 1;
texd.MipLevels = 1;
texd.SampleDesc.Count = 4;
texd.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT;
texd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;

ID3D11Texture2D *pDepthBuffer;
dev->CreateTexture2D(&texd, NULL, &pDepthBuffer);

// create the depth buffer
D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC dsvd;
ZeroMemory(&dsvd, sizeof(dsvd));

dsvd.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT;
dsvd.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2DMS;

dev->CreateDepthStencilView(pDepthBuffer, &dsvd, &zbuffer);
pDepthBuffer->Release();

// get the address of the back buffer
ID3D11Texture2D *pBackBuffer;

swapchain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&pBackBuffer);

// use the back buffer address to create the render target
dev->CreateRenderTargetView(pBackBuffer, NULL, &backbuffer);
pBackBuffer->Release();

//create intermediate render textures
ID3D11Texture2D *pRenderTextureLeft;

D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC textureDesc;
D3D11_RENDER_TARGET_VIEW_DESC renderTargetViewDesc;
D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC shaderResourceViewDesc;

ZeroMemory(&textureDesc, sizeof(textureDesc));


textureDesc.Width = screen_width;
textureDesc.Height = screen_height;
if (oculus){
    textureDesc.Width = (UINT)((FLOAT)textureDesc.Width * oculus->renderScale);
    textureDesc.Height = (UINT)((FLOAT)textureDesc.Height *oculus->renderScale);
}
textureDesc.MipLevels = 1;
textureDesc.ArraySize = 1;
textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT;
textureDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
textureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
textureDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
textureDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
textureDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

dev->CreateTexture2D(&textureDesc, NULL, &pRenderTextureLeft);

renderTargetViewDesc.Format = textureDesc.Format;
renderTargetViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_RTV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
renderTargetViewDesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;

dev->CreateRenderTargetView(pRenderTextureLeft, &renderTargetViewDesc, &pTextureLeftRenderView);

shaderResourceViewDesc.Format = textureDesc.Format;
shaderResourceViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
shaderResourceViewDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0;
shaderResourceViewDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;

dev->CreateShaderResourceView(pRenderTextureLeft, &shaderResourceViewDesc, &pRenderTextureLeftResourceView);

ID3D11Texture2D *pRenderTextureRight;

dev->CreateTexture2D(&textureDesc, NULL, &pRenderTextureRight);

dev->CreateRenderTargetView(pRenderTextureRight, &renderTargetViewDesc, &pTextureRightRenderView);

dev->CreateShaderResourceView(pRenderTextureRight, &shaderResourceViewDesc, &pRenderTextureRightResourceView);

/*if (oculus){
    pOculusOutputDevice = oculus->searchForOculusDisplay(oculus->hmd.DisplayDeviceName);
    swapchain->SetFullscreenState(TRUE, pOculusOutputDevice);
}*/

// Set the viewport

ZeroMemory(&viewportLeft, sizeof(D3D11_VIEWPORT));
ZeroMemory(&viewportRight, sizeof(D3D11_VIEWPORT));
ZeroMemory(&viewportCenter, sizeof(D3D11_VIEWPORT));

viewportCenter.TopLeftX = 0.0f;
viewportCenter.TopLeftY = 0.0f;
if (oculus){
    viewportCenter.Width = (FLOAT)screen_width*oculus->renderScale;
    viewportCenter.Height = (FLOAT)screen_height*oculus->renderScale;
}
else{
    viewportCenter.Width = (FLOAT)screen_width;
    viewportCenter.Height = (FLOAT)screen_height;
}
viewportCenter.MinDepth = 0.0f;
viewportCenter.MaxDepth = 1.0f;

if (dual_mode){
    viewportLeft.TopLeftX = 0.0f;
    viewportLeft.TopLeftY = 0.0f;
    viewportLeft.Width = (FLOAT)screen_width / 2.0f;
    viewportLeft.Height = (FLOAT)screen_height;
    viewportLeft.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    viewportLeft.MaxDepth = 1.0f;

    viewportRight.TopLeftX = (FLOAT)screen_width / 2.0f;
    viewportRight.TopLeftY = 0.0f;
    viewportRight.Width = (FLOAT)screen_width / 2.0f;
    viewportRight.Height = (FLOAT)screen_height;
    viewportRight.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    viewportRight.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
}

devcon->RSSetViewports(1, &viewportCenter);

InitPipeline();
InitGraphics();
}
```

Per request, here is some more code:

I'm including the entire Direct3D class header, so you can see what are and are not member variables.

```
#pragma once

#include "Oculus.h"
#include <OVR.h>
#include "Camera.h"

#include <d3d11.h>
#include <D3DX11.h>
#include <D3DX10.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "d3d11.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx11.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx10.lib")

class Direct3D
{
public:
struct VERTEX{ FLOAT X, Y, Z; D3DXCOLOR Color; FLOAT U, V; };
struct DISTORTION{
    FLOAT LensCenter[2];
    FLOAT ScreenCenter[2];
    FLOAT Scale[2];
    FLOAT ScaleIn[2];
    FLOAT HmdWarpParam[4];
};

IDXGISwapChain *swapchain;             // the pointer to the swap chain interface
ID3D11Device *dev;                     // the pointer to our Direct3D device interface
ID3D11DeviceContext *devcon;           // the pointer to our Direct3D device context
ID3D11RenderTargetView *backbuffer;
IDXGIOutput* pOculusOutputDevice;
ID3D11VertexShader *pVS_Primary;    // the vertex shader
ID3D11PixelShader *pPS_Primary;     // the pixel shader
ID3D11VertexShader *pVS_Distortion;
ID3D11PixelShader *pPS_Distortion;     // the pixel shader
ID3D11Buffer *pVBuffer;     //vertec buffer
ID3D11Buffer *pIBuffer;
ID3D11InputLayout *pLayout_Primary;
ID3D11InputLayout *pLayout_Distortion;
D3D11_VIEWPORT viewportLeft;
D3D11_VIEWPORT viewportRight;
D3D11_VIEWPORT viewportCenter;
ID3D11Buffer *pCBufferPrimaryShader;
ID3D11Buffer *pCBufferDistortionShader;
ID3D11DepthStencilView *zbuffer;       // the pointer to our depth buffer
ID3D11ShaderResourceView *pTextureLeftResourceView;    // the pointer to the texture
ID3D11ShaderResourceView *pTextureRightResourceView;
ID3D11ShaderResourceView *pRenderTextureLeftResourceView;
ID3D11ShaderResourceView *pRenderTextureRightResourceView;
ID3D11RenderTargetView *pTextureLeftRenderView;
ID3D11RenderTargetView *pTextureRightRenderView;
D3DXMATRIX matFinalLeft;
D3DXMATRIX matFinalRight;

Camera cameraLeft, cameraRight;

int screen_width;
int screen_height;

bool dual_mode;

Oculus* oculus;

Direct3D(Oculus* oculus);
Direct3D();
~Direct3D();

void InitD3D(HWND hWnd);     // sets up and initializes Direct3D
void CleanD3D(void);         // closes Direct3D and releases memory
void RenderFrame();
void InitPipeline();
void InitGraphics();
void RenderLeft(ID3D11RenderTargetView *RenderTarget, D3DXMATRIX matFinal, D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport, bool clearRenderTarget);
void RenderRight(ID3D11RenderTargetView *RenderTarget, D3DXMATRIX matFinal, D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport, bool clearRenderTarget);
void DistortionCorrection(ID3D11RenderTargetView *RenderTarget);
void CreateTransforms();
void setVertices();
void setMainShaders();
void OVRMatrix4fToD3DXMatrix(OVR::Matrix4f& source, D3DXMATRIX& dest);
};
```

And here is the code that initializes the image textures (right now they load the same image to two different textures. It's eventually going to be the two sides of the 3D image. Just as soon as i figure out how to access the second image in the file)

FILENAME is #defined as the name of the image file I'm displaying

```
void  Direct3D::InitGraphics()
{


D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile(dev,        // the Direct3D device
    FILENAME,    // load Wood.png in the local folder
    NULL,           // no additional information
    NULL,           // no multithreading
    &pTextureLeftResourceView,      // address of the shader-resource-view
    NULL);          // no multithreading

D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile(dev,        // the Direct3D device
    FILENAME,    // load Wood.png in the local folder
    NULL,           // no additional information
    NULL,           // no multithreading
    &pTextureRightResourceView,      // address of the shader-resource-view
    NULL);          // no multithreading

// get image size for rectangle mesh size
D3DX11_IMAGE_INFO info;
D3DX11GetImageInfoFromFile(FILENAME, NULL,  &info, NULL);

FLOAT textureWidth = info.Width*0.001f;
FLOAT textureHeight = info.Height*0.001f;

// create vertices to represent the corners of the cube
VERTEX OurVertices[] =
{
    { -textureWidth, -textureHeight, 2.0f, D3DXCOLOR(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), 1.0f, 1.0f },
    { textureWidth, -textureHeight, 2.0f, D3DXCOLOR(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), 0.0f, 1.0f },
    { -textureWidth, textureHeight, 2.0f, D3DXCOLOR(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), 1.0f, 0.0f },
    { textureWidth, textureHeight, 2.0f, D3DXCOLOR(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), 0.0f, 0.0f }
};

// create the vertex buffer
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bd;
ZeroMemory(&bd, sizeof(bd));

bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
bd.ByteWidth = sizeof(VERTEX)* 4;
bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
bd.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;

dev->CreateBuffer(&bd, NULL, &pVBuffer);

// copy the vertices into the buffer
D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE ms;
devcon->Map(pVBuffer, NULL, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, NULL, &ms);    // map the buffer
memcpy(ms.pData, OurVertices, sizeof(OurVertices));                 // copy the data
devcon->Unmap(pVBuffer, NULL);


// create the index buffer out of DWORDs
DWORD OurIndices[] =
{
    0, 1, 2,    // side 1
    2, 1, 3,
};

// create the index buffer
bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
bd.ByteWidth = sizeof(DWORD)* 6;
bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
bd.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
bd.MiscFlags = 0;

dev->CreateBuffer(&bd, NULL, &pIBuffer);

devcon->Map(pIBuffer, NULL, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, NULL, &ms);    // map the buffer
memcpy(ms.pData, OurIndices, sizeof(OurIndices));                   // copy the data
devcon->Unmap(pIBuffer, NULL);
}
```

And just in case you need it, here is the initialization of the rendering pipeline.

```
void Direct3D::InitPipeline()
{
// compile the shaders
ID3D10Blob *VS_Primary, *PS_Primary, *VS_Distortion, *PS_Distortion;
D3DX11CompileFromFile("vs_primary.hlsl", 0, 0, "VShader", "vs_5_0", 0, 0, 0, &VS_Primary, 0, 0);
D3DX11CompileFromFile("ps_primary.hlsl", 0, 0, "PShader", "ps_5_0", 0, 0, 0, &PS_Primary, 0, 0);
D3DX11CompileFromFile("vs_distortion.hlsl", 0, 0, "VShader", "vs_5_0", 0, 0, 0, &VS_Distortion, 0, 0);
D3DX11CompileFromFile("ps_distortion.hlsl", 0, 0, "main", "ps_5_0", 0, 0, 0, &PS_Distortion, 0, 0);

// create the shader objects
dev->CreateVertexShader(VS_Primary->GetBufferPointer(), VS_Primary->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &pVS_Primary);
dev->CreatePixelShader(PS_Primary->GetBufferPointer(), PS_Primary->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &pPS_Primary);
dev->CreateVertexShader(VS_Distortion->GetBufferPointer(), VS_Distortion->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &pVS_Distortion);
dev->CreatePixelShader(PS_Distortion->GetBufferPointer(), PS_Distortion->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &pPS_Distortion);

// set the shader objects
devcon->VSSetShader(pVS_Primary, 0, 0);
devcon->PSSetShader(pPS_Primary, 0, 0);

// create the input element object
D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC ied[] =
{
    { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    { "COLOR", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    { "TEXCOORD", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0, 28, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
};

// use the input element descriptions to create the input layout
dev->CreateInputLayout(ied, 3, VS_Primary->GetBufferPointer(), VS_Primary->GetBufferSize(), &pLayout_Primary);
devcon->IASetInputLayout(pLayout_Primary);

dev->CreateInputLayout(ied, 3, VS_Distortion->GetBufferPointer(), VS_Distortion->GetBufferSize(), &pLayout_Distortion);
devcon->IASetInputLayout(pLayout_Distortion);
// create the constant buffer

D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bd;
ZeroMemory(&bd, sizeof(bd));

bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
bd.ByteWidth = 64;
bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;

dev->CreateBuffer(&bd, NULL, &pCBufferPrimaryShader);

devcon->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &pCBufferPrimaryShader);

ZeroMemory(&bd, sizeof(bd));

bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
bd.ByteWidth = 48;
bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
dev->CreateBuffer(&bd, NULL, &pCBufferDistortionShader);
}
```

Pixel Shader:

```
Texture2D Texture;
SamplerState ss;

float4 PShader(float4 color : COLOR, float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0) : SV_TARGET
{
return color * Texture.Sample(ss, texcoord);
}
```

Vertex Shader:

```
cbuffer ConstantBuffer
{
float4x4 matFinal;
}

struct VOut
{
float4 color : COLOR;
float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
float4 position : SV_POSITION;
};

VOut VShader(float4 position : POSITION, float4 color : COLOR, float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0)
{
VOut output;

output.position = mul(matFinal, position);
output.color = color;
output.texcoord = texcoord;

return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the following code, I didn't see how you pass the texture from RenderLeft() to RenderRight(). You just pass backbuffer to RenderRight().

```
RenderLeft(pTextureLeftRenderView, matFinalLeft, viewportLeft, true); 
RenderRight(backbuffer, matFinalRight, viewportRight, false);
```

So the result is the texture rendered to the left viewport and the right viewport only show the color(green) of the backbuffer.

Comment: pRenderTextureLeftResourceView is a resource view linked to the same texture as pTextureLeftRenderView. They are both member variables of the Direct3D class, so they don't have to be passed to the function. I only added parameters, so it was easier to change things when I wanted to test something. RenderLeft should render to pTextureLeftRenderView, and then the shader resource for the same texture is set in RenderRight. The problem isn't with RenderRight using the wrong texture. The problem is that RenderLeft is rendering to the back buffer when the back buffer isn't the render target.

Comment: Can you show more code please? especially the code to load and draw the texture of the dog.

Comment: I edited the question to include a lot more of the code. If there is anything else you think would be relevant. Let me know.